# 'Pure CSS Accordion' auto-closing with Filter Menu

Tags: html, css, accordion

Pure CSS Accordion can be found here: https://codepen.io/raubaca/pen/PZzpVe

My issue can be seen on this URL:
http://prj.sellerdeckwebhosting.co.uk/ks/smr/acatalog/trade-essentials-column-radiators-1.html

The issue is if you expand a sidebar menu e.g 'Height (mm)' and tick an option, the options will then disappear, this is the issue.

```css
.filter-list .tab {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filter-header {
  color: #333;
}

input.filter-head-cb {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.filter-header>label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 3em;
  background: #f6f6f6;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}

.filter-list .blue label {
  background: #2980b9;
}

.filter-list .tab-content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .35s;
  -o-transition: max-height .35s;
  transition: max-height .35s;
}

.tab-content p {}


/* :checked */

input.filter-head-cb:checked+.tab-content {
  max-height: 100%;
}


/* Icon */

.filter-header>label::after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 3;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  -o-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
}

.filter-header>input[type=checkbox]+label::after {
  content: "+";
}

.filter-header>input[type=radio]+label::after {
  content: "\25BC";
}

.filter-header>input[type=checkbox]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotate(315deg);
}

.filter-header>filter-head-cb[type=radio]:checked+label::after {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.filter-list {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.clear-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  right: 6px;
}

.filter-checkboxes {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-list">
  <h4 class="filter-header" id="S_1_66439_0">
    <label for="tab_S_1_66439_0">Height (mm)</label>
    <input class="filter-head-cb" id="tab_S_1_66439_0" type="checkbox" name="tabs" onclick="OnFilter(this);">
    <div id="FilterPropertyOptions_S_1_66439_0" class="filter-checkboxes tab-content">
      <div id="PropOptionTemplate_S_1_66439_0" style="display:none;"><input type="checkbox" value="<Actinic:FilterPropValue></Actinic:FilterPropValue>" id="<Actinic:FilterPropChoiceID></Actinic:FilterPropChoiceID>" actiniccustomselection="" actinicdisabledctrl="" onclick="OnFilter(this);">
        <label for="<Actinic:FilterPropChoiceID></Actinic:FilterPropChoiceID>" actinicdisabledstyle=""><actinic:filterproptext></actinic:filterproptext></label><br></div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="S_1_66439_0" value="300" id="S_1_66439_0-2" disabled="disabled" onclick="OnFilter(this);">
      <label for="S_1_66439_0-2" style="color:gray">300 (0)</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="S_1_66439_0" value="500" id="S_1_66439_0-3" onclick="OnFilter(this);">
      <label for="S_1_66439_0-3">500 (19)</label><br><input type="checkbox" name="S_1_66439_0" value="600" id="S_1_66439_0-4" onclick="OnFilter(this);">
      <label for="S_1_66439_0-4">600 (17)</label><br><input type="checkbox" name="S_1_66439_0" value="750" id="S_1_66439_0-5" disabled="disabled" onclick="OnFilter(this);">
      <label for="S_1_66439_0-5" style="color:gray">750 (0)</label><br><input type="checkbox" name="S_1_66439_0" value="1800" id="S_1_66439_0-6" disabled="disabled" onclick="OnFilter(this);"><label for="S_1_66439_0-6" style="color:gray">1800 (0)</label><br></div>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: took a quick look: found out that:
input.filter-head-cb:checked + .tab-content {
    max-height: 100%;
} 
disappears when clicking the checkbox

Comment: @Edrees Thanks, any ideas why that might be?

Comment: a quick thought would be the OnFilter(this) function on the input checkbox when a certain height is clicked unchecks the checkbox in the header causing it to collapse instead of only applying it to the element itself! As the next time it does work when you repeat it which means (this) is within the scope of the input field whereas in the first click it is not and causes the checkbox to be unchecked which causes the max-height: 100% not work as filter-head-cb is unchecked, for now you can try to debug it and once i have more time, i can take a look more into this... hope this helps